# graphic and activity

Tags: android, image, animation, android-activity

What I'd like to realize is a door, like this (but in 2D): [image]

So i thinked to create it with blender.
The first question is: *how to implement blender image in the activity background?*
After this, my goal is to make animated the door...in other words, allow to the user to move the door for close or open it just tapping and moving it.

What is the way to realize this? What tools I need? How to structure the project?

PS: even if the door in the image is 3D, I will draw it in 2D...more simple.

Comment: I believe you can use OpenGl to display 3D models created in e.g. blender.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you put a png sequence(animation of the door opening) and get the tap-sliding moving from the user, you can make the animation of the door (open/close) just moving back and forward, manipulating the framerate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image as a background with an `ImageView`. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/door" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then in Java, wherever you listen for tap or click events, do something like this

```
ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
background.setImageResource(R.drawable.doorclosed);
```

to toggle to the other image.

Answer (score 0):

Craigy's answer is correct, however, this will produce just two states "Open" and "Closed". Why not create a set or array of images for different phases in the door closing and then use;

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         switch (i){
          case 0:
        plate.setImageResource(R.drawable.door0);
        break;
          case 1:
        plate.setImageResource(R.drawable.door1);
        break;
          case 2:
        plate.setImageResource(R.drawable.door2);
        break;
          case 3:
        plate.setImageResource(R.drawable.door3);
        break;
          case 4:
        plate.setImageResource(R.drawable.door4);
        break;
          }
       }
     },"insert a number for the delay s ie. 10)";
  }
```

to present each image after a small delay. This could be a action initiated by an ontouch event listener  or button click.